# How to find from where rsync is getting generated?

Tags: unix, rsync

In our server below command is getting executed periodically which should be removed. Where can I find the below scheduling and how to remove it?

rsync --server -vlogDtpre.iLsC ./home/test

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: It's probably being called in some user's crontab. Edit it out with `crontab -u <user> -e` . If you don't know the user and the process doesn't show which user is running it, you can try editing /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow to list only the users you'd like to use crontab.

Comment: Thanks you. Its very weird from where this job is being triggered? Is it triggered from Local server or remote server?

Comment: The job is being triggered on the machine where you've found the process. There are many ways to do this. Cron is the most likely. Others may involve being initiated by some remote process, but there must be a process (daemon) on the local server to handle such requests if so. Start with cron. It's the most likely culprit by a wide margin.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su] or [sf] or even [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Not able to find it in the user id corntab. While triggering it also shows: csh -c rsync --server -vlogDtpre.iLsC ./home/test